# Java - When limited to built-in packages, what is the best way to store data in an external file?

Tags: java

I'm really struggling to find any concrete information on how to store data in an external file, when limited to built-in Java packages.

My coursework limits me to not use any third party packages, otherwise I would have used Gson or some other JSON manager, or SQLite.

Which built-in package would you recommend to someone who is new to Java?

Comment: It totaly depend of the type of the data to store, list of same type values can go into a .txt, rather that lots of elements can go into a SQL table ...

Comment: Java has XML parser, that is one of options. There is also preferences file. It all depends on what kind of data you want to store. There is also RandomAccessFile which can be used to create your own DB-like files.

Comment: @azro I'm storing data that interacts with each other across 3 separate file. I built the system using Gson but then was told we can't use third party libraries. What is the SQL manager package name?

Comment: It is `java.sql.*`.  However, that is only the client API.  You also need a database server, and there isn't one in the "built-in Java packages".